# How can I increment by 1 the amount of lines I want to skip in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "cmd=findstr /R /N "^^" Contas.csv | find /C ":""


for /f %%a in ('!cmd!') do set number=%%a




set /A number=%number%-1
```

for each interation I want it to increase skip by 1(starts at 1, then 2,3,4,5...)

```
for /f "skip=1" %%U IN (Contas.csv) DO (
if not defined line set "line=%%U" 
echo !line!

pause
)
```

Comment: could give me an example how to do that ?

Comment: Could you please try to explain your task better. The best way to do that is to provide example content of `Contas.csv`, and with it include the content you're getting now, together with what you actually want that content to be. Click on the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60264545/edit) button and make those changes to your question itself, as opposed to trying to abuse the comment area.

Comment: @Gerhard: `for /f "skip=%var% delims=" ....` works fine (as long as `%var%` is an integer and greater than zero)

Comment: contas.csv is a one column file with different account numbers

Comment: Please explain the actual task, it appears to me that you're asking for help with code which isn't the most efficient way of  achieving the intended goal.

Comment: What I want is to get all the lines, one at a time , and use SendKey to print it on the screen.

Comment: SendKey is not a batch file command!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60264545/how-can-i-increment-by-1-the-amount-of-lines-i-want-to-skip-in-a-batch-file#comment106599270_60264545), and as `SendKey` is not a batch file command, here's my interpretation of the methodology I think you require:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "cmnd="%__APPDIR__%find.exe" /V /N ""<"Contas.csv""
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Skip=1Tokens=1*Delims=]" %%G In ('"!cmnd!"')Do (
    Echo=%%H
    "%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe" 1 /NoBreak>NUL
)
EndLocal
```

I have skipped the first line, using `Skip=1`, *which I assume is your header*, (if you don't wish to skip a header line, then remove `Skip=1`).

Additionally, I have used `Echo=` to output each line, *including any empty ones, (you may be wishing to use `SendKey` here)*.

Finally I have used `Timeout` with a `1` second delay, *to allow you to see the effect of each line being output individually, (this may not be required if you're not using `Echo=`)*.

---

If you'd like to include the record numbers too then a small adjustment to the `Delims` and `Echo=` is necessary:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "cmnd="%__APPDIR__%find.exe" /V /N ""<"Contas.csv""
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Skip=1Tokens=1*Delims=[]" %%G In ('"!cmnd!"')Do (
    Echo %%G    %%H
    "%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe" 1 /NoBreak>NUL
)
EndLocal
```

---

In both cases, if you're not interested in using robust code, you can change `"%__APPDIR__%find.exe"` to `Find` and `"%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe"` to `Timeout`

Comment: It worked,thank you a lot. I have one last question. How would I print these values in a notepad?

Comment: I'm sorry! but I don't understand what you mean by "in a notepad". It cannot be simply to output to a text file, because you said it was a one column file, so you'd simply be copying it, `Copy /Y "Contas.csv" "NewFile.txt"`; Or, if you just wanted it without the header, `More +1 "Contas.csv"<"NewFile.txt"`. I would definitely recommend that you enter `more /?` at the Command Prompt. If you're trying to send each line to an open GUI Text Editor application, and refresh it one line at a time, then you've certainly got a lot more work to do before you'll get help on that as a new question!